# DeepL API adds quotation marks to some translated words, how to avoid this behavior?

Tags: c#, deepl

We are using the [DeepL API](https://www.deepl.com/en/docs-api) to translate some sentences to various languages.

While the overall quality of the translations is great, occasionally `DeepL` is adding some quotation marks between some words on some target translations like `French` or `German`, which causes us some headaches.

Here is a short example

> Input text (English):
> The foo, bars and jobs settings have been added to the dashboard for your convenience.

> Translation (French):
> Les paramètres "foo", "bars" et "jobs" ont été ajoutés au tableau de bord pour plus de commodité.

> Translation (German):
> Die Einstellungen für "foo", "bars" und "jobs" wurden zu Ihrer Bequemlichkeit in das Dashboard aufgenommen.

We didn't expect these quotes at all. **Does anybody know how to disable/suppress these quotes?**

With these quotes, we are being knocked out the moment we want to translate XML content (using the [tag_handling=xml](https://www.deepl.com/de/docs-api/xml) parameter):

```
Input text (English):
The <i>foo</i>, <i>bars</i> and <i>jobs settings</i> have been added to the dashboard for your convenience.
```

```
Translation (French):
Les <i>paramètres "</i> <i>foo</i>", " <i>bars</i> " et " <i>jobs</i> " ont été ajoutés au tableau de bord pour plus de commodité.
```

```
Translation (German):
Die <i>Einstellungen für</i> <i>"foo"</i>, <i>"bars"</i> und " <i>jobs"</i> wurden zu Ihrer Bequemlichkeit in das Dashboard aufgenommen.
```